# Print a 5x5 Grid Map in Lua

Tags: dictionary, lua, grid

I'm trying to figure out how to print out a 5x5 grid map, each place being a room with exits. I have a table with 25 values within, being the exits for each room. If the value is 0, it means there is no room in that position.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to bypass any anomalies that pop up. For example...

```
[ ]         [ ]            
    \     /  |  /          
      [ ]   [ ]   [ ]      
          X  |  /          
            [+]         [ ]
                \     /    
                  [ ]      
                /          
[ ]---[ ]---[ ]
```

It shows me in the middle where the + is, and each of the lines are exits. `\` is southeast, `/` northeast, `|` north/south, `---` east/west, `X` is all diagonal exits. The problem in that example is that the position north of me should be empty, as it is the same room as the one northwest and northeast. So it's printing the same room out twice.

Here's another example of the messed up positions.

```
      [ ]         [ ]---[ ]
    /     \     /  |       
            [ ]   [ ]      
             |  X  |       
      [ ]---[+]   [ ]      
          \     X  |       
            [ ]   [ ]      
                      \    
                        [ ]
```

Empty rooms are just space. Any help would be <3ly ^_^

:: EDIT ::

Here is the code used to print out the maps.

The alias I type in to make it all happen: ^gmap$, and its code:

```
local i = 1
for k, v in ipairs(on.map.info.grid) do
  local x = tonumber(v[2])
  local exits = getExits(v[2])
  local exits2 = {}
  local exits5 = {}
  local exits6 = {}
  local colour = getTerrainColour(v[1])
  if k < 25 then
    exits2 = getExits(on.map.info.grid[k+1][2])
    if k < 20 then
      exits5 = getExits(on.map.info.grid[k+5][2])
    end
    if k < 20 then
      exits6 = getExits(on.map.info.grid[k+6][2])
    end
    diagExit(i, exits, exits2, exits5, exits6)
  end
  southExit(exits, i)
  if i % 5 ~= 0 then
    if x > 0 then
      local space = k == 13 and "+" or getRoomSpacer(exits) or " "
      cecho(string.format("<%s>[%s]", colour, space))
    else
      echo("   ")
    end
    space = eastExit(exits, exits2) or "   "
    echo(space)
  else
    if x > 0 then
      local space = k == 13 and "x" or getRoomSpacer(exits) or " "
      cecho(string.format("<%s>[%s]", colour, space))
    else
      echo("   ")
    end
    echo("\n")
    if i <= 20 then
      for i = 1, 4 do
        echo(tmp.sx[i])
        echo(tmp.dx[i])
      end
      echo(tmp.sx[5])
      echo("\n")
    end
  end
  i = i + 1
end
```

The relevant functions:

```
function parse_exits(s)
   on.map.exits = {}
   for x, stat in s:gmatch("(%a+)(%d)") do
      on.map.exits[x] = stat
   end
end

function getTerrain(n)
   n = tonumber(n)
   local terrain = {
      [1] = "Forest",
      [2] = "City",
      [3] = "Swamp",
      [4] = "Underground",
      [5] = "Snow",
      [10] = "Freshwater",
      [11] = "Saltwater",
      [12] = "Beach",
      [13] = "Mountain",
      [15] = "Tropical",
      [26] = "Skies",
   }
   for k, v in pairs(terrain) do
      if k == n then return v end
   end
   return false
end

function getTerrainColour(n)
  local terrain = getTerrain(n)
  local tcolours = {
    Forest = "forest_green",
    City = "light_goldenrod",
    Swamp = "DarkOliveGreen",
    Underground = "a_brown",
    Snow = "snow",
    Freshwater = "a_blue",
    Saltwater = "spring_green",
    Beach = "yellow",
    Mountain = "brown",
    Tropical = "orange_red",
    Skies = "light_sky_blue",
  }
  return tcolours[terrain] or "red"
end

function getExits(n)
   n = tonumber(n)
   local x = {}
   local exits = {
      {"n", 1},
      {"ne", 2},
      {"e", 4},
      {"se", 8},
      {"s", 16},
      {"sw", 32},
      {"w", 64},
      {"nw", 128},
      {"u", 256},
      {"d", 512},
      {"in", 1024},
      {"o", 2048},
   }
   local i = 12
   while n > 0 do
      if n >= exits[i][2] then
         x[#x+1] = exits[i][1]
         n = n - exits[i][2]
      end
      i = i - 1
   end
   return x or 0
end

function getRoomSpacer(t)
  local xlist = {
    u  = [[^]],
    d  = [[_]],
    ["in"] = [[>]],
    o  = [[<]],
  }
  if table.isMember(t, "u") and table.isMember(t, "d") then
    return "="
  else
    for x, s in pairs(xlist) do
      if table.isMember(t, x) then
        return s
      end
    end
  end
  return false
end

function eastExit(t, t2)
  if table.isMember(t, "e") or table.isMember(t2, "w") then
    return "---"
  end
  return false
end

function southExit(t, pos)
  if pos > 5 then
    pos = pos % 5
  end
  tmp.sx = tmp.sx or {}
  if table.contains(t, "s") then
    tmp.sx[pos] = [[ | ]]
  else
    tmp.sx[pos] = [[   ]]
  end
end

function diagExit(pos, t, t2, t5, t6)
  if pos > 5 then
    pos = pos % 5
  end
  tmp.dx = tmp.dx or {}
  if table.isMember(t, "se") and table.isMember(t2, "sw") then
    tmp.dx[pos] = [[ X ]]
  elseif table.isMember(t, "se") then
    tmp.dx[pos] = [[ \ ]]
  elseif table.isMember(t2, "sw") then
    tmp.dx[pos] = [[ / ]]
  elseif table.isMember(t5, "ne") then
    tmp.dx[pos] = [[ / ]]
  elseif table.isMember(t6, "nw") then
    tmp.dx[pos] = [[ \ ]]
  else
    tmp.dx[pos] = [[   ]]
  end
end
```

`cecho` prints out in colour, hence the terrain function to get the colours...

Here is the data used for the first printout error:

```
{
  {
    "1",
    "136"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "50"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "138"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "50"
  },
  {
    "2",
    "32"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "139"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "36"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "162"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "148"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "76"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "66"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  }
}
```

And for the second printout:

```
{
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "168"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "54"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "192"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "154"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "177"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "12"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "75"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "177"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "128"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "137"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "0",
    "0"
  },
  {
    "1",
    "136"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and the data used to generate these two maps?

Comment: Sure. It's all there now - forgive the sloppiness!